# NP-complete problems where the inputs are prime numbers

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, np-complete, primes

Are there (well?) known NP-complete problems where the input(s) is(are) a(some) prime number(s), with complexity measured relative to the binary length of the input number(s)? I am thinking there are probably some, me just being an ignoramus.  Could you provide references?

Comment: You might find something here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems.
if there is such a problem i doubt if its well-known.

Comment: For whatever reason this comes to my mind https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.14764

Comment: @TayfunPay Thanks for the link! I mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: @TayfunPay. Thanks for pointing out that interesting article.

Answer (score 7):

There are no known NP-complete problems whose input would consist of primes <sub>(or, say, $k$-tuples of primes, or even more complicated structures as long as they contain at least one prime of length $\ge n^\epsilon$, where $n$ is the total length of the input, and $\epsilon>0$ is a constant).</sub>

The existence of such problems (even completely artificial) would require better deterministic prime generators than what is currently known. Specifically:

> **Observation:**
>
> 1. If there are polynomial-time functions $f,g$ such that $g(f(w))=w$ for all $w\in\{0,1\}^*$ (which implies $f$ is injective), and the output of $f$ consists entirely of primes, then there exist NP-complete languages whose inputs are primes.
> 2. Assuming the [Berman–Hartmanis conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berman%E2%80%93Hartmanis_conjecture), the converse also holds.

**Proof:**

$1\to2$: Fix any NP-complete language $L$. Then the language $L'=\{x\text{ prime}:g(x)\in L\}$ is in NP as it reduces to $L$ via $g$, and it is NP-hard as $L$ reduces to it via $f$.

$2\to1$: Let $L$ be an NP-complete language on primes. We can consider it as a language on arbitrary inputs such that all non-primes are rejected. Assuming the Berman–Hartmanis conjecture, $L$ is paddable: there is a poly-time function $h(x,w)$ with a poly-time left inverse $h'(z)$ such that $x\in L\iff h(x,w)\in L$. Fix a prime $p\in L$.  Then the requirements hold for the functions $f(w)=h(p,w)$ and $g(z)={}$the second element of the pair $h'(z)$.

**Notes:**

- For specific NP-complete languages known so far, the conclusion of the Berman–Hartmanis conjecture is typically easy to show.
- The implication $1\to2$ does not quite need the existence of a poly-time $g$; it is enough to assume that $f$ is injective and $|f(w)|\ge|w|^\delta$ for some constant $\delta>0$.
- A (necessarily sparse) language $L$ is **P**-*printable* if there exists a poly-time function $h$ such that $h(1^n)$ outputs the set $\{w\in L:|w|\le n\}$. If there exists a function $f$ as above, then e.g. $\{f(1^n):n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a **P**-printable infinite set of primes. This is a much weaker requirement than the existence of an $f$ as in the Observation, nevertheless even the existence of a **P**-printable infinite set of primes is an open problem; see the discussion in https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.14764 .
- If you relax the question to allow NP languages on primes that are NP-hard under *randomized* poly-time reductions, then such languages *do* exist, as you can construct $f$ and $g$ as above where $f$ is randomized poly-time (and $g$ is still deterministic).

  E.g., let $f(w)$ be a randomly chosen prime of length $|w'|^2$ whose binary expansion starts with $1w'$, where $w'$ is a prefix-free encoding of $w$ (e.g., if $w=w_0\dots w_{n-1}$, let $w'=1w_01w_1\dots1w_{n-1}0$), and let $g(x)$ decode the prefix of $x$.

  This construction can be derandomized assuming [Cramér’s conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture).

Comment: Thank you for your insightful and useful answer. I am actually curious as to the consequences of such a problem existing. Perhaps I will post that as another question, pending some further investigations into this matter.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it has an official name, but this problem is NP-complete (actually it's a simple "number theory" reformulation of the exact cover by 3-sets problem):

Given a set of $3n$ triprime numbers; find if there is a square-free product of $n$ of them. The problem is NP-complete even if their factors are given in the input.

Comment: If you allow as an input a long list of small primes in this manner, then you can trivially encode any problem by “primes”: e.g., encode a string $w_1\dots w_n\in\{0,1\}^n$ by the list $(2+w_1,\dots,2+w_n)$. I don’t think this is what the OP had in mind.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: I agree, but the problem in my answer has an almost "natural" interpretation: a list of triprimes as input and asks for a square-free product. Up to my knowledge, I think it's the closest to what the OP asked, but let's see his opinion.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, Marzio. The problem might be here that you are measuring complexity relative to n (not even the binary length of n), rather than the binary length of the prime numbers themselves? Perhaps you could clarify this?

Comment: @EGME Could *you* clarify what you mean by this? The definition of NP and NP-completeness is such that complexity is measured with respect to the total length of the input. Here, the length of the input is not quite the parameter denoted as $n$, but it is close: the input is a list of $9n$ primes, each of binary length $O(\log n)$ (this is not specified in the problem statement, but the reduction showing NP-completeness gives this). Thus, the length of the input, which is the *sum* of the lengths of the primes involved, is $O(n\log n)$, whereas the *individual* primes have length $O(\log n)$.

Comment: We may assume triprime numbers with no square factors, then each triprime number is equivalent to a set of exactly three primes, and you are looking for n sets with no common element. Map the i-th prime to the number i, and it's the same problem with no primes involved.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek. Thank, you, you have actually clarified it very nicely. The total input length is exponentially larger than the length of any of the primes. I am looking for a problem where you are working relative to the binary length of the primes themselves.  I guess I did not explain that clearly enough in the post.

Comment: @EGME: then my answer is useless; if you allow randomization then you can artificially use larger primes (find a set of primes of binary length $O(n)$), but without randomization there are no known methods (see Emil's answer)